# android error Dx trouble writing output: already prepared Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: classes.dex

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to use google map for location but i used google play services but while referencing google play service library to my project its give me error as :

Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared

[2014-08-11 19:33:43 - MainActivity] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: classes.dex

Origin 1: E:\workspace\MainActivity\bin\classes.dex

Origin 2: E:\workspace\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\com.android.location.provider.jar

Please help me for solving this issue